# Am I crazy? Demos on jQuery's 'effects' page not working in any browser

Tags: firefox, browser, website, firebug, jquery

I want to make sure I'm not crazy, because I can't get any of the effects demos to work on jQuery's demo pages. I thought it might be my new Firebug version (1.5.2) or Firefox in general, but they're not working in IE or Chrome either.

Here are the links where the demos aren't working. One is for highlight, and the other is for explode. Incidentally, highlight is the one that I'm trying to use. Could it be the new jQuery UI version? Is anyone else having these not work?

[Effect 1](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/effect)
[Effect 2](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight)

Comment: Not working for me in Chrome 4.1.249.1021 (beta) or IE7 - looks like either you're not insane or we're both sharing hallucinations.

Answer (score 1):

Before you assume it's a problem in Firefox 3.6, do these demos work in *any other* browser?

I can confirm nothing happens in FF3.6, but I don't see them working in Firefox 3.5 or IE7 either.

And some of the demos ([clearQueue](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/), and [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)) work fine in all those browsers, including FF3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem to work in Firefox 3.6, I do not have Firebug installed.  In fact, I disabled all my extensions a while to in order to track down a freezing bug in FF.

Answer (score 0):

Both effects are not working in Safari 4.0.4 too !